# Running python application through pm2

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, interpreter, pm2

I have a script which is written in `Python` and the application is setup in such a way that you need to enable `virtual env` to run the application.
There is a filewith the name of `startProcess.py` if you run the application with `python startProcess.py` it will throw the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "startProcess.py", line 1, in <module>
    import pika, sys, os
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pika'
```

But, when I enable the env using `.\venv\Scripts\activate` command and then run the script, the process will start as expected. All the packages are installed to the `venv` only.

I need this code to be running in background, and the solution which I'm going with is `pm2`.

I've installed `NodeJS` & `PM2` as global, tried to run the script using the `pm2 start startProcess.py`, the application failes to start with the same error as above. I did some research and followed [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127834/how-to-run-a-python-script-like-pm2-for-nodejs) process to create a `ecosystem.config.json` and aded some configurations to that file. My config files looks something like below.

```
{
    "apps": [{
        "name": "app_name",
        "cwd": "<---absolute_path_to_project_dir--->",
        "script": "./startProcess.py",
        "exec_mode": "fork_mode",
        "instances": "1",
        "wait_ready": true,
        "autorestart": false,
        "max_restarts": 5,
        "interpreter" : "<---absolute_path_to_project_dir--->\\venv\\Scripts\\python"
    }]
}
```

When I run the start script `pm2 start ecosystem.config.json`, the application works as expected. but the problem is, it will open the `python.exe` inside the `venv\Scripts\python.exe`, which we've provided as `interpreter` will pop the empty terminal window as showin in the below screenshot.

[image]

When I close the `python.exe` terminal window, the process will also get stopped. Screenshot below.

[image]

The Code is running in `windows` server, due to some restrictions, we can't use `linux` servers to deploy the code.

I've also referred the official documentation, and tried both `cluster_mode` and `fork_mode`. I did not understand the difference between both modes much, but the configuration which I added above will work with `fork_mode` properly and will throw the same error as I mentioned earler for `cluster_mode`.

Only 1 change which I can make is setting `autorestart` to `true` and when I close that `python.exe` terminal, `pm2` will restart the process, and open new `python.exe` window.

**Accepted Criteria:**

Coniguration which is metioned above is fine, but the `interpreter` (python.exe) should not be opopped up as new terminal window. It can be running in background, but everything else is fine as configued above. As of now.